# Wordpress: get link title

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink, tags, title, jgrowl

I want to use the jGrowl plugin with my custom wordpress theme. 
my case: you click on a link and a growl-like message box opens. My message should be the link's title text.

But how can I echo/display this title? where can I get it from? I already did some research but couldn't find any solution.

(I really don't mean "the_title()" .. more like this one `<a href="" title="">`

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. (But then, I don't know what the jGrowl plugin is) are you looking to change that plugin? Or do you need something on the template's end? Maybe show some of the code you're using right now

Answer (score 0):

just google it: "php get title from url".
You'll find some php classes. 
You can use them to get Title of page from given url and use it in jGrowl.
Cheers!